# Getting PHP $resquest empty even though consoling proves the opposite

Tags: php, post, get, request

I am working on a POST method and through the console I can see that the parameters exist.

[consoling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJqq2.png)

But when I test in the PHP code if the `$request` is empty it returns true. Here is the code:

```
if (empty($request)) {
    $auth = Account\Authenticate::login(
         $request['username'],
         $request['password'],
         isset($request['keep'])
    );
}
```

I set the request_order under php.in to "PG" but stills the same problem, am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some more context? What framework are you using? Where does the `$request` variable come from?

Comment: That condition also doesn't make much sense. If `$request` is *empty*, fetch data from it?

Comment: I am working on an existing project developed by a developer that I couldn't reach the &request come from an external library called PHPwag, exactly from form.php under this library and I can say that it  a custom form and that &request works exactly like &_request in php, the point is this project is working on prod that's way I believe the problem is coming from my server or  permission restrictions .

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick response I added the condition to test if the &resquest is empty or not and yes I was sure it was empty because the instruction after the condition is no longer working.

Comment: Try second one. If your ajax request is posting data successfully then that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by setting the property "httponly" to false, this parameter belongs to the function "session_set_cookie_params" under Kernel.php which means enabling SSL for the project, after running the project again I was asked to add an exception to the browser, the project now runs correctly, Thanks.

```
session_set_cookie_params(
    $_sess_cookie_params['lifetime'],
    $_sess_cookie_params['path'],
    $_sess_cookie_params['domain'],
    false,
    false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP's builtin request handling, the global variable is called `$_REQUEST`, not `$request`.

`$_REQUEST` is a global variable provided by PHP. `$request` has no special meaning. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: I am working on an existing project developed by a developer that I couldn't reach, the &request comes from an external library called PHPwag, exactly from form.php under this library and I can say that it a custom form and that &request works exactly like &_request in php, the point is this project is working on prod that's way I believe the problem is coming from my server or permission restrictions

Comment: when I change $request to $_REQUEST the if (!empty($_REQUEST)) the proceed to the instructions but when I console.log($_REQUEST['username']) I get an empty log, is there a better way to print it?

Comment: what about `$_POST` ?

Comment: Hi, $_POST is empty too

Comment: Maybe it's worth investigating this issue on a clean Apache sandbox in the same environment. Install Apache with PHP, create a very simple page that prints out `$_REQUEST` and visit the page from the browser with some GET parameters. Then try to post to the URL using Postman or curl. Next, move the working script to the webserver you've tried it on so far, but remove all other code. If that stops working there's a configuration error in your webserver, otherwise the other code is clearing out $_REQUEST after handling the data maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if ($request) {
    $auth = Account\Authenticate::login(
         $request['username'],
         $request['password'],
         isset($request['keep'])
    );
}
```

or

Add this in your function

```
public function Yourfunctionname(Request, $request)
        if ($request) {
            $auth = Account\Authenticate::login(
                 $request->get('username'),
                 $request->get('password'),
                 $request->get('keep'))
            );
        }
```

Comment: What is the output of dd($request->all()); put this code before if condition is it printing some value or not?

Comment: hello, thanks for your response no it is not printing values, actually after adding it the whole form disappeared.

Comment: This means you got nothing from your request. Are you trying to posting from ajax?

Comment: Yes I am posting from ajax.

Comment: when I change $request to $_REQUEST the if (!empty($_REQUEST)) the proceed to the instructions but when I console.log($_REQUEST['username']) I get an empty log, is there a better way to print it?

Comment: ok, I did this                                                                                                  $message2= $_REQUEST;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

console.log($message2);

</script>"; and now I have this in the console  Array()
​
from: function from()
​
isArray: function isArray()
​
length: 1
​
name: "Array"
​
of: function of()
​
prototype: Array []
​
Symbol(Symbol.species): undefined
​
<prototype>: ()

Comment: Inspect your web and in see in network tab is your request success or not?

Comment: `Request, $request` looks wrong, should probably be `Request $request`